# Unable to enable offline persistence and cache size for Firebase Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to enable offline persistence and increase the cache size for Firebase Firestore in a Flutter App.

I did refer to the [official documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#access-data-offline) as listed on the Flutter website.

Below is the code that I have written for the same:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
      persistenceEnabled: true, cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I see red swirly lines underneath the Settings method with the below message:

> The name 'Settings' is defined in the libraries 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/settings.dart' and 'package:netapp/screens/app_drawer.dart (via package:netapp/screens/screens.dart)'.  Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Searching for the error message shows some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Try+using+%27as+prefix%27+for+one+of+the+import+directives%2C+or+hiding+the+name+from+all+but+one+of+the+imports.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I did check out, but nothing of much help :(

Comment: I'm not flutter expert but it seems there is a conflict between two packages in relation to the name `Settings`. just change your import to `import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' as firestore;` and when using Settings you should use it like `firestore.Settings()`. Important to mention also that you don't need to enable offline persistance as that enabled by default for mobile apps. However, you can increase the cache size or use [`CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size)

Comment: Thanks @Methkal, I'll give it a try and see, if it works.

Comment: Do it like this

    final value = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    value.settings = Settings(persistenceEnabled: true, cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED);

Answer (score 1):

The default value is 40 MB. The threshold must be set to at least 1 MB, and can be set to Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED to disable garbage collection.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#configure-cache-size

Hope this will help someone.

```
void main() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
  const Settings(cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED);
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to import this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```